# SQL statement returns only rows that exist also in the joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot figure out how to form a proper SQL statement for this. I want to get every row from products table but filter the results if certain value in other table is larger than something.

My current statement returns every row that I want to filter correctly but I was unable to make it instead filter the current result and print everything else

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.product_id = p.product_id AND order_date < somedate 
WHERE o.id IS NULL
```

I want it to print whole products table except filter row if orders table column order_date is smaller than the given date,

Edit: thanks for everyone who helped me with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You think too complicated. You want records from table products where a certain order not exists. So say NOT EXISTS in your where clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM orders
  WHERE product_id = products.product_id 
  AND order_date < somedate 
);
```

(You can solve this with an outer join, which alwyays looks a bit quirky in my eyes. Be aware: When outer joining, don't use the outer joined tables fields in the where clause, cause they would be null for an outer joined record of course.)

Comment: Indeed I did! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.product_id = p.product_id AND order_date < somedate and o.id IS NULL
```

Comment: If `order_date` is not `NULL`, then I'll bet that `o.id` is not `NULL` either.

Comment: This one gets every row from products but does not limit the results if orders table somedate is < given date

Comment: remove order_date < somedate from left join and put it in where clause

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.product_id = p.product_id 
WHERE o.id IS NULL AND order_date < somedate
```

Just move the condition into the `WHERE` section

Comment: @GordonLinoff why not? get joined data and the leave only necessary ones

Comment: Let's see, if `o.id` is NULL then `order_date` is NULL too.  Many other responders made the same mistake.  I commented on yours because it was the first I saw.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you need to filter the result set, mention the condition in `WHERE` clause.
Whenever you need to filter the table you are joining with, mention the condition in `JOIN` Condition. Had it been an `INNER JOIN`, it would have worked. But the scenario is a lot different in case of `LEFT OUTER and RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.

So the query becomes:-

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE o.id IS NULL
AND order_date < somedate
```

Comment: This won't work. If o.id is NULL then `order_date` is NULL too.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.product_id = p.product_id 
WHERE o.id IS NULL AND order_date < somedate
```

Comment: This one gives me the results I want to filter away

Comment: okedokey - well show us your table schema and some sample data and we'll try again

Answer (score 1):

Printing "everything else" is not simply a negation of this query.  The focus is on the `products` table and, presumably, you don't want duplicates.  You could use `except` for this purpose.  Here is another approach:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from orders o
                  where o.product_id = p.product_id AND
                        o.order_date >= somedate
                 );
```

This will return products that do not have an order on or after the given date.

Note that this will return products that have no orders.  I am unclear on what to do with those.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the code like that (seems quite rare), really good text for me as I have just started doing stuff with sql